# Java regular expression with lookahead

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, regex-lookarounds

is there a way to print out lookahead portion of a regex pattern in java?

```
    String test = "hello world this is example";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\s(?=\\w+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
    while(m.find())
        System.out.println(m.group());
```

this snippet prints out :

> hello
>  world
>  this
>  is

what I want to do is  printing the words as pairs :

> hello world
>  world  this
>  this
>   is
>  is example

how can I  do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply put capturing parentheses inside the lookahead expression:

```
String test = "hello world this is example";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\s(?=(\\w+))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
while(m.find()) 
    System.out.println(m.group() + m.group(1));
```

Comment: Nice. I was going to suggest `\w+\s(?=(\w+))\1` without changing the Java code, but this consumes the capturing group...